# Detecting outliers along the distribution using the standard deviation in a scatter plot R plotly

Tags: r, charts, plotly, linear-regression, standard-deviation

In R, I need to detect the outliers of this scatterplot, made with plotly.
In particular, I want to select all points that fall outside a certain threshold. Apologies for the screenshot, it's just to give an idea.
[image]

I have the dataframe df with Vol1, Vol2 and sd (that is the standard deviation calculated for Vol and Vol2, for each row). I then considered the threshold as the mean of Vol1 (and later Vol2) + 3 times the mean of the sd. I think that the problem is the way i'm calculating the thresholds, but I'm really struggling in the maths behind this. Here it is part of the code:

```
outlier_threshold_x <- mean(df$Vol1) + 3 * mean(df$sd)
outlier_threshold_y <- mean(df$Vol2) + 3 * mean(df$sd)

p<-plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Vol1, y = ~Vol2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", width = 700, height = 700,
       marker = list(symbol = "cross",size = 4, opacity = 0.5, color = "rgba(50,50,50,0.5)",alpha = I(0.8)))

outliers <- df[(df$Vol1 > outlier_threshold_x) | (df$Vol2 > outlier_threshold_y), ]

p %>% add_markers(
data = outliers,
x = ~Vol1,
y = ~Vol2,
marker = list(color = "red", symbol = "x")
)
```

Can you please explain me how to retrieve the outliers?

Comment: Seems the question is more "how do I identify bivariate outliers" than "how do I do this in R". So you'll probably find the answer over at CrossValidated, e. g.: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53227/test-for-bivariate-outliers